# why is it wrong to say: "Nowadays women have a considerable more role."

Tags: grammaticality

Is it wrong to say: "Nowadays women have a considerable more role."
Grammatically speaking why exactly is it wrong?

Comment: A more _what_ role? "have a more considerable role" (i.e. "aren't ignored as much as they used to be")?

Comment: It's **a + more + adjective + role** e.g. *women should play (or have)  a greater role in the sciences*. You cannot have *a more role* but an actor can play ***many roles*** and in a long successful career she or he  may play **more roles** than another actor.

Comment: Perhaps you mean *Nowadays women have a considerably larger role*? It isn't clear what you are trying to express, so it's difficult to say exactly what is wrong. Please edit your post to provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

More should not be used to modify role. There are other problems as well but that one is too distracting.